# Dust vs. Undust?

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs, prefixes, negative-prefixes

The entry for "*dust*" from LDOCE says:

> **dust<sup>1</sup> (n.)**
>
> 1. [uncountable] `→ HOUSEHOLD` dry powder consisting of extremely small bits of dirt that is in buildings on furniture, floors, etc. if they are not kept clean:
>
>    *All the furniture was covered in dust.*
> 2. [uncountable] `→ HOUSEHOLD` ...
> 3. [uncountable] `→ INDUSTRY`, `HARD SCIENCE` ...
> 4. a dust (BrE) `→ CLEANING` the act of dusting something:
>
>    *I need to give the sitting room a dust.*
> 5. ...
>
> ---
>
> **dust<sup>2</sup> (v.)**
>
> 1. `→ CLEANING` to clean the dust from a surface by moving something such as a soft cloth across it:
>
>    *Rachel dusted the books and the bookshelves.*
> 2. ...
> 3. ...

Now, the entry for "*undust*" from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undust) says:

> **undust (v.)**
>
> 1. (obsolete) To free from dust.

I do notice the entry being marked as "obsolete" for *undust*, and also I remember my [English](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/start-with-english-howe/1002163595?ean=9780194336307) classes as a child where we had a rectangular cubic sponge called a "*duster*" that we used to **dust/undust** the chalk on the blackboard, however every time I'm cleaning my desk, computer, furniture, etc. I'll automatically think of "**undusting**" and then will force myself to undo and say "**dusting**" instead, just to convince myself that the latter is the grammatical one; however I can't see the logic behind this verb and its usage based on general English grammar.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undust&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cundust%3B%2Cc0) also shows up some results (even if not many) for *undust*:

[image: A usage frequency graph for "undust". The first, and highest, peak occurs around 1883, then it drops back to zero for a few years, then there's a bit of activity between 1903-1943, then another gap, then a slowly-increasing curve from ~1960-1998, after which it tails off (but doesn't go down to zero).]

Is *undust* incorrect? Did it exist as a correct verb years ago, and can I still use it?

I feel paranoid to say: "*I'm dusting my keyboard!*" because it makes me feel that it has the opposite meaning, as if I'm spreading dust and particles on my keyboard, especially since these chores aren't all that commonly spoken with today's lifestyle, and stating the former sentence might sound a bit odd.

P.S. Note that "***dust something off***" is slightly different in usage e.g. "*They were dusting off leaves and twigs.*", and based on my understanding from the definitions in dictionaries, saying "<del>I'm dusting my keyboard off.</del>" isn't correct.

Comment: Contextually "I'm dusting my keyboard!" is appropriate and acceptable as it refers to the act of dusting. I've never heard the word "undust" used. A variation I've come by is "dust off".

Comment: What's unclear about *dust²* = "to clean" and *undust (obsolete)*?

Comment: @MegaMark Yeah, but "*dust something off*" is slightly different, since it indicates that you're removing that *something* off by *dusting* it. e.g. *They were dusting off leaves and twigs.*

Comment: But when you are dusting off your keyboard... are you not removing dust...? It's just not repeated, "They were dusting off dust from their keyboards"

Comment: @AndrewLeach I updated my post.

Comment: 'Give [the room] a dust' is best seen as an idiom; otherwise someone will be asking "Why is 'a' used with a noun that doesn't take a plural here?"

Comment: @MegaMark I think it's not correct to say it that way. See my updated post.

Comment: It's not obsolete in OED(2), neither are both meanings of _undusted_. My earlier comment has bit the dust it appears.

Comment: I don't have access to OED @Frank, so please put it here if you think it's appropriate as an answer for this question. (:

Comment: The intransitive usage of 'dust [the thing in need of cleaning] off' is licensed by the [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dust+off): "[The metaphorical sense derives from] the literal meaning of 'dusting yourself off' (cleaning dirt off yourself) after you fall". Obviously, there's **always** an implication of the stuff needing to be removed.

Comment: It's not an answer as such, just pointing out that LDOCE is at odds with a slightly older version of OED - what's more surprising is that LDOCE does NOT have a definition for _undusted_ at all.

Comment: True @Frank, I suppose LDOCE is doing its best to keep everything **contemporary**! But yeah, there are entries that it doesn't have. However searching online, I couldn't find many reliable sources for "undust" either.

Comment: The first few dictionaries I've checked in giving 'undust' flag it as 'obsolete', except Webster's (1913). It's a matter of whether you'd rather feel paranoid until the feeling wears off, or sound ridiculous to 99.99% of anglophones. But no, I didn't downvote.

Comment: On the lack of _undusted_ in LDOCE, surely it is still a contemporary usage for ... If you're desk is covered in dust, and you dust it all off except for your keyboard, you have left you're keyboard _undusted_. (DV not from me - in fact +1)

Comment: @Frank That's also a subtle point that I hadn't thought of. I still think all that information can be collected as an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Same to your comments; they have useful info that I think can be gathered as an answer for this question. (:

Comment: oerkelens has given the answer I'd give.

Comment: Even in the (presumably now always) current version of OED online _undust_ is not marked as obsolete. I can't make an answer (of sorts) because I can't copy from the OED due to copyright restrictions. If you want to collect my comments up and add them to your question feel free. I'd trust OED over LDOCE. _undust_ might not be in common use but obsolete seems harsh.

Comment: OED still takes time to update. The entry for *undust* (as in "remove dust") is marked as not completely updated; the last update was in 1921. The last real citation dates from 1654; a citation from *Notes & Queries* in 1884 is really a pun. It was certainly rare by 1921, and it's entirely reasonable to suggest that it's obsolete now, even if OED hasn't quite caught up yet.

Comment: Relevant: [Is “unpeeling an orange” grammatically correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85558/is-unpeeling-an-orange-grammatically-correct)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Undust* is used so little that you should indeed see it as *obsolete*. That ngram shows some results is not really relevant if you compare it with the occurences of [*dust*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undust%2C+dust&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cundust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdust%3B%2Cc0).

Your paranoia is uncalled for, there is really no proficient, let alone native, speaker of English that will think that dusting your keyboard is similar to watering your plants.

I can understand where your hesitation to use it comes from, as you seem to be saying to opposite of what you are doing. Actually, to complicate matters, *dust* is used in the sense of *adding dust* as well: *lightly dust the cake form with flour*.

In context, however, there will usually be absolutely no confusion. When you dust your keyboard, everyone will understand that you are cleaning it.

As to the logic behind one word meaning two different (opposite) things, we are talking about English, the language that uses words like *inflammable*, and in which people say *I could care less* when they mean the opposite. Don't get stuck too much on logic when it comes to natural language!

Comment: I didn't compare it with "*dust*" in NGrams, because it'll definitely include all the noun forms of the word, in addition to the verb ones that are much more common...

Comment: True - to avoid the nouns, try comparing [_dusting_ and _undusting_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undusting%2Cdusting&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdusting%3B%2Cc0) . They can only be verb-forms, and undusting doesn't appear _at all_. (My browser spell-checker doesn't accept _undust_ and _undusting_ btw...)

Comment: Right. Neither does mine :D, but it doesn't accept many other correct words like "realise", "humour", "travelling", etc. but yeah, thank you for the information.

Comment: @Neeku - those words are a matter of American vs British spelling :) If you tell your browser that you want to use AmE, then "humour" is not correctly spelled...

Comment: Neeku -- regarding the fact that "dust" can mean two opposite things.  This is utterly unsurprising and normal in English. You can give any number of examples like that where, "logically" a word does "not make sense."  It's just no big deal; it's irrelevant and normal in the language.

Comment: @JoeBlow Those words are called auto-antonyms or contronyms. See also: cleave, custom, oversight, sanction.

Comment: +1 Perhaps the most pertinent point: "Don't get stuck too much on logic when it comes to natural language!"

Comment: In the same vein, consider the difference between *watering* a cow and *milking* a cow.

Comment: @oerkelens not to put too much weight on what the browser dictionary says though. I have to add real words all the time. A recent addition was `analyte`. Definitely a word, yet absent.

Comment: @Brad - it never is an argument for a word's non-existence! I discovered elsewhere today that ditransitive is not a word according to my browser. The thing is _quite_ illiterate. :)

Comment: @Bobson I don't see the difference...in both cases you're pouring a liquid on the cow so it grows, right?  :P

Comment: @rob - Totally.  Maybe we should try *juicing* the cow and see if that also helps it grow...

Comment: @Kyle - magnificent work on the contronyms, cheers!

Comment: @Bobson Gah! Now you're making my brain itch even more! I recently bought a device that *core*s pineapples! Similar logic somehow.

Answer (score -5):

"undust" is obsolete at best, or more likely just "not a word".

"Is undust incorrect?"  Yes, it's that simple: undust is incorrect.

"can I still use it?"  Absolutely **not**, you quite simply can not use it. It's that simple.

Note: You seem to have found "undust" in "wikitionary". You can dismiss "wikitionary" as a language source, it's just an unlike scribble board.

Note: There's a **great danger** on this site: here, a speaker learning English is asking: "Hey I saw this weird word 'undust' mentioned, is that a word??"  The full and complete answer has two letters: the answer is "No".

Of course, one could have an arcane discussion about how often that typo is used, was it a word historically, does it occur in print, etc. But it's really just plain not relevant. In the fullness of the question, the sense of the question, the answer is just "no, that's not a word dude."

Comment: I'd certainly label it 'obsolete' in spite of the OED stance. Other dictionaries label it so, and the OED isn't infallible. Perhaps they're picking up perverse usages such as that contrived for [Amelia Bedelia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelia_Bedelia).

Comment: Right - heh good one on Amelia :)

Comment: According to dictionary.com, Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary also contains the word "undust", marked as obsolete.

Comment: OMG! The Amelia is awesome @EdwinAshworth. (: Also, see Frank's last two comments up there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I never imagined I'd find Amelia Bedelia being used as an example of perversion! What a day!

Comment: There is no danger. This site is specifically _not_ for people learning the language and is for "arcane discussion". Especially when it pertains to an obsolete word and not a typo as you incorrectly labeled it. Also note that the OP is asking whether it was ever a word so your answer is not really helping.