# Is “Untap” an equivalent of “Unleash?”

Tags: word-usage, verbs, prefixes, derivational-morphology, negative-prefixes

While attempting to [assist another user on another Stack Exchange site](https://superuser.com/q/1113489/167207) I stumbled upon this marketing page for the [Samsung SSD 850 EVO](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/850evo.html) that—to my mind—oddly states:

> **Untap your computer’s potential**

Shouldn’t that be:

> **Unleash your computer’s potential**

Or perhaps just use “tap” like this:

> **Tap your computer’s potential**

That “untap” seems like a badly used un-word in that copy. And not for nothing that same page—in a callout near the top left—uses “unleash” to state a similar marketing sentiment:

> Unleash the power of performance and endurance.

I searched through the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/untap) for *untap* and it states, “The word you've entered isn't in the dictionary.” Yet, [a search for “untapped” yields a definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/untapped); but again nothing for “untap.” And [results for the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=untap) similarly show nothing for “untap” but [shows a result for “untapped.”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/untapped)

Comment: It is a weird mishmash that seems to try to give the reader a sense of some "untapped potential." But "untap the potential" means exactly the opposite; you want to be tapped into this hidden power for as long as you can.

Comment: "Untapped" is a perfectly standard adjective (which might describe the computer's potential before Samsung did something to it), but the OPs first example looks like an instance of "verbing weirds language". Life would be dull if there were no Japanese computer documentation to read, though.

Comment: Maybe the author was a Magic: The Gathering player? Where untapping something makes its abilities ready for reuse.

Comment: Just for those saying they haven't seen examples: one from the [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2011/01/25/AR2011012506715.html) and a letter from the [Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB120787474260006693)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Untap" does not seem to be a commonly used word.

Most dictionaries I've looked at do not have an entry for a verb *[untap](http://www.onelook.com/?w=untap&ls=a),* although they do for the adjective *[untapped](http://www.onelook.com/?w=untapped&ls=a),* which is actually an antonym of "unleashed." I think "untapped" is commonly used in the collocation "untapped potential." It's similar to how *[unopened](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unopened&ls=a)* exists as an adjective, but there is no corresponding verb "to unopen" (although *[unopen](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unopen&ls=a)* apparently has been used as an adjective meaning "closed").

So I agree that this is badly worded. A more usual way to phrase this would be "[Tap into](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tap%20into&ls=a) your computer's potential."

In general, the prefix *un-* seems to be attached more commonly to adjectives (including ones derived from past participles like "tapped" or "opened") than to verbs. Bea Bonmot's answer to the following question "[Prefixes for Perishable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321623/prefixes-for-perishable/321631#321631)" cites Ben Zimmer's article "[The Un-Believable Un-Verb](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/the-un-believable-un-verb/)," which says that according to Yale linguist Laurence Horn, the verb prefix *un-* actually is derived in part from a different historical source, "the reversative prefix on(d)- (related to German ent- and Greek anti-)." Colin Fine's answer to the following question "['Unselect' or 'Deselect'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/unselect-or-deselect/18516#18516)" says

> Until quite recently, the "un-" prefix for verbs was pretty much
>   limited to what Whorf called the "cryptotype" of verbs to do with
>   fastening, wrapping, enclosing: "unlock, unwind, unwrap, unstrap,
>   unfasten, untie, unlatch, unroll" - there were a very few exceptions
>   like "unsay" (which is highly literary). [...] The adjectival prefix "un-" is a different matter, and has long been very widely applicable.

The meaning of the prefixed verb "to untap" (in the sense of "to unleash") fits in fairly well with the prefixed verbs above, but the meaning of the unprefixed verb *[tap](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tap&ls=a&loc=home_ac_tap*)* does not fit in very well with the unprefixed verbs of "fastening, wrapping, enclosing."

The Oxford English Dictionary has an entry for the verb *untap,* but it is not defined and has only two examples, both from the seventeenth century:

> 1622   J. Mabbe tr. M. Alemán *Rogue* ii. 229   If I should suffer her
>   still to vntap my vessel, she would suck me dry at last. 
> 1689   N. Lee
>   *Princess of Cleve* ii. iii,   Does not your Politician,..after all his
>   Plotting, Drudging and Sweating at Lying, retire to some little Punk
>   and untap at Night?

It says it is derived from the verb *tap* and the senses 7 and 9 of the prefix *un-*:

> 7. With rare exceptions, the Old English verbs in *un-* are
>   transitive, and this has always remained the prevailing use. In Middle
>   English, however, intransitive uses of some common words are found, as
>   *unbend, unclose, unlouk,* and in casual formations as *unbody.* In the
>   later language the usage increases to some extent (as in *unfold,*
>   etc.), but is chiefly confined to words having some currency.
>   
> [...] 
> 9. The redundant use of *un-* is rare, but occurs in Old
>   English *unlíesan,* and Middle English *unloose,* which has succeeded in
>   maintaining itself. Later instances are *unbare, unsolve, unstrip*
>   (16–17th cent.), and the modern dialect forms *unempt(y), unrid, unthaw*
>   (also locally *uneave*). Another redundant or extended use (= ‘peel
>   off’) exists in *unpeel* v.

So one existing verb with similar semantics to *untap* is *[unloose](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unloose&ls=a),* which is basically synonymous to *[loosen](http://www.onelook.com/?w=loosen&ls=a).*
There has already been a question on ELU about *unpeel*: "[Is "unpeeling an orange" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85558)" The following question about *undust* also seems relevant: "[Dust vs. Undust?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189755)"

Also, here is a Language Log post with a lot of relevant links: "[Why do *thaw* and *unthaw* mean the same thing?](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004179.html)"

Comment: All these `un-` verbs reminds me of ["unbreak" and "uncry"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2Rch6WvPJE), but it seems almost any verb denoting an action that is naturally reversible can be prepended with `un-` or `de-`.

Comment: This good question has 2 CV for   lack of research. The good answers show that it is not an easy and straitforward  issue, plus OP question actually makes some informed points on what they are asking. Should the question be put on hold,anyway? Are close voter probably too zealous and too anxious to see this question  put on hold?

Comment: 'although unopen apparently has been used as an adjective meaning "closed"' - it might be just me but unopened jar would be a jar which was never opened while closed jar would be jar which was opened and then closed.

Comment: Considering it's for an SSD, a product marketed to a particular group, perhaps 'tap' here is instead referring to its use in the card game Magic: The Gathering. In that game, 'tap' is a synonym for 'exhaust'; a 'tapped' card cannot be used. 'Untapping' therefore has a positive connotation, and the copywriter for this ad didn't bother looking up what 'tap' *actually* means.

Answer (score 12):

There's a lot going on here. 
Both verbs have an [*un-* prefix](http://ling.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/horn/Horn2005_UnpaperMcCawley.pdf), in the sense of 'remove'; 
*unleash* means 'remove the leash' and *untap* means 'remove the tap'.
In either case, some encumbrance is released.

If you untap a container of fluid, the fluid comes out; if you unleash a dog, the dog is freed.
So far, so much the same.

However, *tap* and *leash* are also verbs without *un-*, and they mean quite different things.
If you *tap* a container of fluid, the fluid comes out; if you *leash* a dog, the dog is constrained.

So *unleash* is the opposite of *leash*, but *untap* is **not** the opposite of *tap*.
The use of *untap* seems limited to metaphorical contexts; it's rare to talk about "untapping a new barrel" in a bar; one would use *tap* for the physical activity.

But metaphorically, ...

- *Untap your secret powers!*
- *Tap your inner strength!*

(or vice versa) sound equally good (or bad, depending on tastes).

Comment: So if you *untap* your *untapped resources* are they *tapped* or *untapped*?

Comment: Ask your guru; I wouldn't know.

Comment: Native American English speaker here and I've never heard or read *untap* used like this. Do you have any references for this?

Comment: Native English English speaker here and I've never heard or read `untap` used in this context. Do you have any references for this?

Comment: In fact I have never ever seen the "verb" `untap` before, except in the context of Magic the Gathering.

Comment: Re: *tap your inner strength*, shouldn't it be *tap **into** your inner strength*?

Comment: @Aron. An example of the phrase "untapped potential' is in this article I happened to be reading this morning. http://www.espn.com/olympics/trackandfield/story/_/id/17315417/allyson-felix-heartbroken-coming-short-dive-400-meters or is that not the thing you are disputing?

Comment: @MartinSmith I said I have never seen the VERB, untap. You are talking about the ADJECTIVE untapped. I had never said I've never seen that adjective before. But similarly the adjective cannot be conjugated to form "untap".

Comment: I think there is a great deal of popular misunderstanding of what a _tap_ is. Some people think it is the stopper of a barrel (others call that the _bung_), while some think it is the spigot. To those who view _tap_ as a closure, _untap_ has the same sense as _unleash_; the fact that they may well know the verb _tap_ as well is irrelevant; we're familiar with words whose opposites mean the same thing, like _ravel_ and _unravel_. To those who actually understand that the tap is not a permanent closure whose removal opens something, _untap_ makes no sense.

Comment: 'Untap' is not limited to metaphorical use; maple trees are routinely tapped and untapped.

Comment: There we go. In the right context, _tap_ refers to something that can be removed or inserted, changing state as it does so; so provisional _tap_ 'insert tap' contrasts with privative _untap_ 'remove tap', just like _plug_ and _unplug_.

Answer (score 7):

It's a mistake.  The writer doesn't know the definition of "tap" that could apply here and is too focused on creating an image of released power to care.

Lack of knowledge and disregard for the tools of the trade can result in disaster in most contexts, but here it merely makes a fool of the "writer," who probably still won't care.

On the bright side, it's a phenomenon that results in ridiculous non-words that we CAN choose to find amusing. Two of my personal favorites:  When I went to my first sewing class, I was told to bring a seam-ripper in case I ever needed to "unpick" something I had sewn.  As well, I know people who plan their evening meals around what is in freezer that they can "unthaw" after getting home from work.

Grrrrr or giggles;  this one seems harmless so far.

Comment: Yes; my current favorite is the verb you get from the adjective _undefeated_. The question is what (for example) _Trump will undefeat Clinton_ (or vice versa) could possibly mean. Especially this year.

Answer (score 4):

"Untap" is being inappropriately used in the quoted line.

To "tap" (in this sense) is to to

> draw out, from, or upon: *tap new sources of revenue*, *the story taps
>   powerful emotions* [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tap)

The most familiar use of the term (in the US) in this sense is to *tap* a maple tree (drill a hole in it) to extract its sap.

Thus, an *untapped* resource is one which has not yet been somehow utilized.  Saying "Untap your computer's potential" is a bit of nonsense implying that you should do nothing to unleash the device's capabilities.

(It's likely that many folks are confused by beer kegs -- not the stuff within them but the kegs themselves.  A "virgin" keg conceptually has no hole in the side, and it is necessary to "tap" (drill) it -- similar to *tapping* a tree -- to access the fluid inside.  What confuses things is that the thing inserted into the hole is then often referred to as a "tap", leading folks to believe that "untap" means to remove a plug from the hole, when in reality "untapped" means that there is no hole.)

As to the suggestion that the prefix *un-* can legitimately be used as a sort of intensifier, I'll point out that, while *unloosed* is pretty much never used as an adjective to mean "not yet loosed", *untapped* is used with the meaning "not yet tapped" with considerable frequency.  To use the word in essentially the opposite sense is inviting confusion and is to be (strongly) discouraged.

The line should have said "Tap your computer's potential", though "Unleash ..." would probably sound better.  Likely its author conflated "untap" and "unleash".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *untap* has the sense of *unleash*.

As you point out, the word doesn't appear in any online dictionary referenced by [oneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=untap&ls=a), except [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=untap), which lists a usage that is unrelated to either *tap* or *(un)leash*.

An [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tap%20*%2Cuntap%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ctap%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btap%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20water%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20root%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btap%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cuntap%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Buntap%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buntap%20a%3B%2Cc0) search indicates that *untap* is rarely used, but when it *is* used, it's normally used in the sense of *unleash*. It's also often related to mental potential. Here are a few examples:

- One particular dream was that a scientific means could be found to untap the great unused potential of the human mind. [- Dick Kovan, New Scientist](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=KDjf7u8ZcboC&pg=PA64&dq=%22untap%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ4-D9vsPOAhUMI5QKHe__By8Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22untap%20the%22&f=false)
- Practice is the more direct way to change behaviour, e.g. the way in which meetings are conducted influences the possibility of creating new knowledge or untap the potential of the existing knowledge of the group. [- Building the Knowledge Economy: Issues, Applications, Case Studies, edited by P Cunningham, M Cunningham, P Fatelnig](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=TzUYxvwW51EC&pg=PA820&dq=%22untap%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ4-D9vsPOAhUMI5QKHe__By8Q6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22untap%20the%22&f=false)
- Being enjoyable and open-ended, they seem more than many other classroom methods, when rightly handled, to untap a little of the ambrosian motivation. [- A Davison, Games and Simulations in Action](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=kY4nAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22untap%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpw-7-vsPOAhWONpQKHW6eC00Q6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22untap%20a%22&f=false)

Here's another example from a web search, also related to potential:

- Untap your potential, get the full experience - [untap.it](http://untap.it/untap-your-potential)

The last site includes Sir Richard Branson, a prominent businessman, as its Ambassadorial President.

Based on the above, it would be reasonable for a business advertisement to use the term *untap* in the sense of *unleasing* some kind of potential.